# React useState conversion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, mern, model-viewer

I made a static webpage app that I have been slowly converting to React (MERN stack) to make it more dynamic/so I won't have to configure each and every HTML document. It's a product configurator that uses Google's model-viewer.

I'm fairly new to using a full-stack workflow but have found it pretty fun so far! I am having trouble however understanding on how to convert some of my vanilla JS to work within React. This particular script will change a source/3D model when a user clicks on a button. Below is a code snipit of what I have working currently on a static webpage.

```js
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from "react-redux";

// Actions
import {getProductDetails} from "../redux/actions/productActions";

const ProductScreen = ({match}) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const [currentSrc, setCurrentSrc] = useState()
    const [srcOptions, setSrcOptions] = useState()


    const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.getProductDetails);
    const {loading, error, product} = productDetails;


    useEffect(() => {
      if (product && match.params.id !== product._id) {
        dispatch(getProductDetails(match.params.id));
        setCurrentSrc(product.src);
        setSrcOptions(product.srcList);
      }
    }, [dispatch, match, product]);
```

```html
return (
<div className="productcreen">
  {loading ? (
  <h2> Loading...</h2>) : error ? (
  <h2>{error}</h2>) : (
  <>
    <div className='sizebuttons'>
    {srcOptions.map((src) => (
        <button onClick={() => setCurrentSrc(src)}>{src}{product.size}</button>
    ))}
    {srcOptions.map((src) => (
        <button onClick={() => setCurrentSrc(src)}>{src2}{product.size2}</button>
    ))}
    {srcOptions.map((src) => (
        <button onClick={() => setCurrentSrc(src)}>{src3}{product.size3}</button>
    ))}
    </div>
    <div className="productscreen__right">
      <model-viewer id="model-viewer" src={currentSrc} alt={product.name} ar ar-modes="scene-viewer quick-look" ar-placement="floor" shadow-intensity="1" camera-controls min-camera-orbit={product.mincameraorbit} max-camera-orbit={product.maxcameraorbit} interaction-prompt="none">
        <button slot="ar-button" className="ar-button">
                    View in your space
                  </button>
      </model-viewer>
    </div>
    </> )} )};
```

Here is what the DB looks like:
[image: CurrentDB]

The "product.size" is being pulled in from MongoDB, and I'm wondering if I could just swap models with: "product.src","product.src2","product.src3" (which is also defined in the DB already) I'm assuming I need to use useState in order to switch the source, but I am unsure. Any help would be greatly appreciated! If you'd like to see the static webpage of what I'm trying to accomplish, you can view it [here](https://cashcredenza.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/index.html) if that helps at all.

Here is how the products are being exported in redux:

```js
import * as actionTypes from '../constants/productConstants';
import axios from 'axios';

export const getProductDetails = (id) => async(dispatch) => {
  try {dispatch({type: actionTypes.GET_PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST});

    const {data} = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`);

    dispatch({
      type: actionTypes.GET_PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: actionTypes.GET_PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
      payload: error.response && error.response.data.message ?
        error.response.data.message :
        error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook from React to create the state. After you fetch your product from the DB you can set the initial value with `setCurrentSrc` or if it's coming from props, you can set the initial value like this: `const [currentSrc, setCurrentSrc] = useState(props.product.src)`.

Then change the src of your model-viewer to use the state value so it will automatically rerender if the state value changes. Lastly, add onClick handlers to some buttons with the `setCurrentSrc` function to change the state.

```js
const ProductViewer = (props) => {
  const [currentSrc, setCurrentSrc] = useState()
  const [srcOptions, setSrcOptions] = useState()

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const { loading, error, product } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.getProductDetails
  )
  useEffect(() => {
    if (product && match.params.id !== product._id) {
      dispatch(getProductDetails(match.params.id))
    }
  }, [dispatch, match, product])

  // update src and srcOptions when product changes
  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentSrc(product.src)
    setSrcOptions(product.srcList)
  }, [product])

  return (
    <div className="productscreen__right">
      <model-viewer
        id="model-viewer"
        src={currentSrc}
        alt={product.name}
        ar
        ar-modes="scene-viewer quick-look"
        ar-placement="floor"
        shadow-intensity="1"
        camera-controls
        min-camera-orbit={product.mincameraorbit}
        max-camera-orbit={product.maxcameraorbit}
        interaction-prompt="none"
      >
        <button slot="ar-button" className="ar-button">
          View in your space
        </button>

        {/* add your switch buttons somewhere... */}
        {/* this assumes you have a srcList, but this could also be hardcoded */}
        {srcOptions.map((src) => (
          <buttton onClick={() => setCurrentSrc(src)}>{src}</buttton>
        ))}
      </model-viewer>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I will see what I can achieve and report back! I am using useEffect, useSelector, and useDispatch to retrieve my parameters. Like so: `const dispatch = useDispatch(); const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.getProductDetails); const { loading, error, product } = productDetails; useEffect(() => { if (product && match.params.id !== product._id) { dispatch(getProductDetails(match.params.id)); } }, [dispatch, match, product]);`

Comment: Ok, cool. I just edited the code sample based on your comment. Try it out and lmk.

Comment: Alright, I played around with it last night and some more this morning, and I get no error in the VSCode terminal when I save it! However, the browser throws an error saying `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`
I'm assuming it's because I don't have a srcList like you mentioned above. Instead everything is inside one JSON document, so maybe I just need to re-format my DB? I've edited my question above on how the DB looks as well as how I'm exporting that out in redux and such.

Comment: Ayyyy I got it after more fumbling around with it!! Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction! Now to move onto the other problem haha. I basically used what you had originally but left out `setSrcOptions(product.srcList)` as I had no srcList, and then I had to tweak the button slightly to `<buttton onClick={() => setCurrentSrc(product.src)}></buttton>` I also left out the `{srcOptions.map((src) => ())}` part as that was causing it to not work either. I will go ahead and mark yours as the answer though as I'm sure someone else could have a similar/different setup than me.